# Swift 4: Zoom in on a location other than User Location

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to find a way, programmatically, to zoom in on a location other then the user location. Say, for instance, I want to zoom into MIT, using only its name, what should I do?

Comment: http://sweettutos.com/2015/04/24/swift-mapkit-tutorial-series-how-to-search-a-place-address-or-poi-in-the-map/

Comment: kindly add some more details to the question. like which map SDK you're using? any code snippets of what you've done so far?